# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using `chartjs` to display a pie, radar and a bar chart. The data is rendered successfully in all the three cases . But the pie chart is not displayed. I am getting the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined`

Below are the `pie.js` and the `index.jade` template files.

```
pie.js
    'use strict'

    $(function(){
    var data = [{
            value: 300,
            color: "#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
        }, {
            value: 50,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
        }, {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
        }];

        var options = {};
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart3");
        $('#myChart3').find('.canvas').first().addClass('active');
        var myLineChart1 = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
    });
```

```
index.jade
    extends layout
    block extraHeader
        script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js")
        script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js")
        script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js")


    block content
        .jumbotron
            .container
                p Welcome to #{title} area.
            .container(id="c1")
                canvas(id="myChart2", style="width:200px;height:200px")
            .container(id="c3")
                canvas(id="myChart3", style="width:200px;height:200px")
            .container(id="c2")
                canvas.canvas(id="myChart", style="width:200px;height:200px")

        script(src="/javascripts/charts/radar.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/charts/bar.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/charts/pie.js")
```

`myChart2` and `myChart` are used by bar and radar chart scripts.

I have tried using different fiddle versions and adding setting active class for `myChart3`. 

How to solve this error?

Comment: Could it be that #myChart3 doesn't have a child with ".canvas" class?

Comment: What can I do in that case?

Comment: This is basically a `NullPointerException`. Look up how to debug such an issue. This is an extremely common problem, so a search should bring up many results.

Comment: It might work without the find(.canvas) bit